# Random number between two range

Tags: c++

rand() or qrand() functions generate a random int.

```
int a= rand();
```

I want to get an random number between 0 and 1.
How I can do this Work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate a random `int` into a `float`, and then divide it by [`RAND_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/), like this:

```
float a = rand(); // you can use qrand here
a /= RAND_MAX;
```

The result will be in the range from zero to one, inclusive.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is the largest value that the generator will return, so the range goes to one, inclusive.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, it's inclusive on both ends. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Using C++11 you can do the following:

Include the random header:

```
#include<random>
```

Define the PRNG and the distribution:

```
std::default_random_engine generator; 
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
```

Get the random number

```
double number = distribution(generator);
```

In [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) and in [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/) you can find some references about `uniform_real_distribution`.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Generating_random-value_integers_in_Qt) post, it shows how to use qrand for your purpose which is afaik a threadsafe wrapper around rand().

```
#include <QGlobal.h>
#include <QTime>

int QMyClass::randInt(int low, int high)
{
   // Random number between low and high
   return qrand() % ((high + 1) - low) + low;
}
```

Comment: I like the fact that this answer solves the solution from first principles. The formulae is difficult to reason with but practically the easiest to implement without the use of additional libraries.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

//
// Generate a random number between 0 and 1
// return a uniform number in [0,1].
inline double unifRand()
{
    return rand() / double(RAND_MAX);
}

// Reset the random number generator with the system clock.
inline void seed()
{
    srand(time(0));
}


int main()
{
    seed();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << unifRand() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a module from the random number which will define the precision. Then do a typecast to float and divide by the module.

```
float randNum(){
   int random = rand() % 1000;
   float result = ((float) random) / 1000;
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Simple, working solution. Just one gotcha: If the module (1000 in this case) is not evenly divisible by `RAND_MAX`, then the random numbers produced by this will be slightly biased towards generating smaller numbers, compared to the large ones in the range.